# Nested left and right braces

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to align three left braced equations, the first two with some conditions and also right braced with a range of validity. The third equation will not have any conditions, but must have another range of validity. The three equations have to be aligned at left, the two conditions also aligned at left, and the ranges also aligned at left. I have tried to nest left and right braces using the construction below, but it didn't work, because the third line gets not aligned. I'd appreciate having some help in this issue.

```
\newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\}}
\newenvironment{lcases}
  {\left\{\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right.}
\begin{equation*}
\psi_n(x)=
\begin{lcases}
\begin{rcases}
  \cos(n\pi x/a)\,, &\text{  $n$ even}\\
  \sen(n\pi x/a)\,, &\text{  $n$ odd}
\end{rcases}                  &\text{, } \abs{x} \le a/2\\
  0\,,                        &\text{  } \abs{x} > a/2
\end{lcases}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Can you make your example complete, so it can be compiled without modifications? I assume `\sen` should be `\sin`, and `\abs` is not a standard command (I think). That said, `amsmath` already has a `cases` environment, and `mathtools` (which extends `amsmath`) has an `rcases` environment. Why not use those?

Answer (score 2):

With `cases` and `rcases` from `mathtools`, instead of your custom `lcases`/`rcases`, and moving a comma, you get this:

[image]

Is that what you're after?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\abs{}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\psi_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
\begin{rcases}
  \cos(n\pi x/a)\,, &\text{  $n$ even}\\
  \sin(n\pi x/a)\,, &\text{  $n$ odd}
\end{rcases}                  &\text{, } \abs{x} \le a/2\\
  0                           &\text{, } \abs{x} > a/2
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `cases` for the outer alignment. However, I think it's more helpful for the reader to just use three cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\psi_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
\begin{rcases}
  \cos(n\pi x/a)\,, &\text{  $n$ even}\\
  \sen(n\pi x/a)\,, &\text{  $n$ odd}
\end{rcases},               &\abs{x} \le a/2\\
  0\,,                      &\abs{x} > a/2
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\psi_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
\cos(n\pi x/a)\,, &\text{$\abs{x} \le a/2$, $n$ even} \\
\sen(n\pi x/a)\,, &\text{$\abs{x} \le a/2$, $n$ odd} \\
0\,,              &\abs{x} > a/2
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using nested `array` structure to avoid defining `\newenvironment`, here is how

```latex
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\psi _n \left( x \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\left. \begin{array}{lc}
\cos{\frac{n \pi x}{a}} , & n~\mathrm{even} , \\
\sin{\frac{n \pi x}{a}} , & n~\mathrm{odd} , \\
\end{array} \right\} & x \leqslant \frac{a}{2} \\
\left. \begin{array}{l}
0 , \\
\end{array}\right. & x > \frac{a}{2} \\
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

And here is how its output looks like

> [image: nested left and right braces]

The last line has to be written with another `array` in order to get aligned with equations in first two lines.